# Does anyone know of any bagpipe albums I could buy that have just 2 or 3 bagpipes performing together?

Tags: instrumental, folk, album

Does anyone know of any bagpipe albums I could buy? Not massed pipes (i.e. lots of pipes, sometimes up to 100), but 2 or 3.
I really like the Triumph Street Band, from Canada, but I don't think they have any albums. But that's the kind of thing I'm looking for. They have a "pure, clear sound" (as a reviewer put it) that I like.

Comment: In the Breton tradition the combo of [Bombard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombard_(music)) and [Biniou Koz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binio%C3%B9_kozh)  is found, and there are albums of duos playing these. Strictly speaking only the Biniou Koz is a bagpipe (chanter), but the sound of both is "bagpipish". Leaving this as a comment - you can follow lists of names in the Bombard article to investigate further.

Answer (score 2):

A search for "Bagpipe duo" found

- > Scottish Duo [Hamish Moore and Dick Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nontraditional_bagpipe_usage) recorded two albums, available on Greentrax, in the early 1990s.
- Branschke Armstrong Duo, "[Antithesis](http://amazingpipes.net/)"

A search for "Bagpipe trio" turned up

- [The Griff Trio](http://www.griff.be/EN/albums.html)
- [The Great Highland Bagpipe: Solos, Duos, Trios, Quartets & More - Piping Variations](https://music.apple.com/ca/album/great-highland-bagpipe-solos-duos-trios-quartets-more/394898169) (the track list includes artist names and would provide fodder for additional searches)
- [Fred Morrison Trio: "Live at the Glasgow Royal Concert Hall"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Morrison) (available on various music purchase websites)
- [Erwan Keravec, "Sonneurs"](http://www.erwan-keravec.eu/en/album/sonneurs/)
- [Moebius, "August"](https://www.jonswayne.com/downloads)

A search for "Bagpipe quartet":

- The [winners and list of participants](https://www.pipesdrums.com/article/2019-international-quartet-champions-field-marshal-montgomery/) in the 2019 Piping Live! Glasgow International Piping Festival. That list could be searched to see which groups have albums available.
- The above site also includes the [2007](https://www.pipesdrums.com/article/Updated-SLOT-wins-Piping-Live-quartets/), [2016](https://www.pipesdrums.com/article/inveraray-wins-2016-international-quartets/), and [2017](https://www.pipesdrums.com/article/inveraray-2017-quartet-champions/) winners and participants.

Comment: Note, if something else is desired:   bagpipe is an instrument with widely varying names, such as [Musette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musette_de_cour), Dudelsack/Sackpfeife and [Zampogna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zampogna).

Answer (score 1):

If one bagpiper is enough you could listen to Christina Pato (she plays Galician pipes). She recorded at least one album ("Latina"), but there's also plenty of her music on YouTube, for example:

.

Comment: @user24353 The SE way of thanking is to upvote answers and accept one of them.